# Why isn't this free product of groups abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-groups

I'm trying to prove that the free group $A=A_1*A_2$, where $A_1, A_2\neq 1$ is not abelian. Following the hints below:

Let $x,y\in A_1*A_2$, where $x\neq y$.

Suppose now $A_1=F(S)$ and $A_2=F(T)$, where $S=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ and $T=\{\beta_1,\ldots\beta_m\}$

Let $x,y\in A_1*A_2$, where $x\neq y$, then we have the words

$x=\alpha_1^{n_1}\ldots\alpha_k^{n_k}$ and $y=\beta_1^{m_1}\ldots\beta_l^{m_l}$

Thus using the definition of the operation of the free products, we have

$x\cdot y=\alpha_1^{n_1}\ldots\alpha_k^{n_k}\beta_1^{m_1}\ldots\beta_l^{m_l}$

$y\cdot x=\beta_1^{m_1}\ldots\beta_l^{m_l}\alpha_1^{n_1}\ldots\alpha_k^{n_k}$

Am I correct so far?

I can't continue from that point, since $k$ and $l$ can be different.

Thanks

Comment: What do you know about the definition of a free product?

Comment: Your claim as stated is false: $1 * 1 \cong 1$, and $1$ is certainly abelian.

Comment: @YACP I'm talking about free groups

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm talking about free groups

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, sorry, you're right, I will edit my question

Comment: Well, actually $1$ is free. And with the assumption that neither $A_1$ nor $A_2$ is trivial, your claim holds (not only for free groups!), plainly by the definition of free product.

Comment: @Berci yes, I realized that, I've already edited the question

Comment: I don't see why this question should deserve a down vote. Hence I will up vote to cancel the down vote.

Comment: The claim is obvious for free groups: the free product of free groups is again a free group, and any free group on more than one generator is non-abelian. Otherwise some work is needed: the easiest way to proceed is to find a pair of homomorphisms $A_1 \to S$, $A_2 \to S$, $S$ non-abelian, such that the subgroup generated by the union of the images of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is non-abelian.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean free product, not free group? $A$ is only a free group if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both free groups...

Comment: @user1729 yes, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are free groups.

Comment: I still can't understand what's going on here: If $\,A\,$ is a free group, then expressing it as a *free product* $\,A=A_1*A_2\,$ (as this is the meaning of the operation * in group theory) means that both $\,A_1\,,\,A_2\,$ are free groups themselves, but then why in the hell use this to talk about a *free group*?!

Comment: The existence of free products is frequently shown using words of finite length with elements of the factors as letters. This construction obviously yields a non-abelian group, because by construction the words $a_1a_2$ and $a_2a_1$ for elements $a_1\in A_1\setminus 1$ and $a_2\in A_2\setminus 1$ are different.

Comment: I edited your question to change your statement to "$A_1, A_2$ free groups", and then I realised you had added in the line "I'm trying to prove first for finitely presented free groups $A_1$, $A_2$." So, again, are you trying to do it for all groups $A_1$, $A_2$ or just for free groups?

Comment: @user1729 all free groups, sorry I'm really a beginner in this subject, maybe I'm using some wrong definition.

Comment: There are two (related) concepts - free groups and free products. The result holds for all non-trivial groups, not just free groups (a free product of non-trivial groups is always non-abelian). I am just confused because in your question you say you want to do the case of free groups first, which implies you will do the other cases after.

Comment: @user1729 ok I'm going to edit the question, thank you

Comment: Is there a reason for the algebraic topology tag?

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes, good question, usually we can study this also in algebraic topology courses, in fact I'm studying this in my algebraic topology course right now. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find a clue for this question as follows which should be verified independently.

> If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ are nontrivial elements in $A*B$, then $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ has infinite order and so the above group is an infinite centerless group$^1$.

$1$. An introduction to the Theory of Groups by J.J.Rotman.

If this clue is useful for paving the way of any answer, I will delete it. :)

Comment: [While it is of course of infinite order, we only need the much much weaker fact that $[a,b]$ is nontrivial. Moreoever, this is why the free product $A*B$ is nonabelian when $A,B$ are *any* nontrivial groups. Why would we bother restricting ourselves to $A,B$ free groups, or bother restricting ourselves to finitely presented groups, OP?]

Comment: @anon: Exactly! we just need to see that $[a,b]\neq 1$. I saw a problem at this book before in chapter of free products. I just added this strongest fact, maybe it helps the OP and others to get out of this speech so soon. Sorry if I did nothing for the OP. Sorry.