# Difference between elements of a free product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that we have two non-trivial groups $G$ and $H$. I want to show that their free product is non-abelian. Does it suffice to take $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ with $|g|>1$, $|h|>1$ and consider the words $[g,h]$ and $[h,g]$ or are these actually the same word?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't this free product of groups abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246399/why-isnt-this-free-product-of-groups-abelian)

Comment: Indeed, $G\ast H$ is a centerless infinite group (for $G$,$H$ being non-trivial), hence non-abelian.

Comment: So are those two words distinct in a free product?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\langle g\rangle *\langle h\rangle$ injects canonically into $G*H$, hence we may assume wlog that $G$, $H$ are cyclic (with generators $g,h$). To show that the free product is non-abelian, it suffices to find a group $X$ and group homomorphisms $\phi\colon G\to X$, $\psi\colon H\to X$ where the images of $g$ and $h$ do not commute in $X$. Let $X$ be the group of isometries of the $2$-sphere, $\phi(g)$ the rotation around the $x$-axis (i.e., the line $(1,0,0)\cdot\Bbb R$) by $\frac{2\pi}{|g|}$ (or by $\frac\pi2$ if $|g|=\infty$), and $\psi(h)$ the rotation around the line $\ell=(1,1,0)\cdot\Bbb R$  by $\frac{2\pi}{|h|}$ (or by $\frac\pi2$ if $|h|=\infty$).
Then $\phi(g)\psi(h)\phi(g^{-1})$ is a non-trivial rotation around the line $\phi(g)\ell\ne \ell$. In particular, $\phi(g)\psi(h)\phi(g^{-1})\ne\psi(h)$, as desired.

If preferred, the above can be spelled out in form of $3\times 3$ matrices. Also, one can work with orthogonal axes instead of the somewhat artificial $\ell$ except in the case $|g|=|h|=2$.